# Parse this value with moment doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have a date value like this `value.game_date = 2013-10-27 03:39:35` and I'm trying to parse it as follow:

```
moment().format(value.game_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

But I get this as result `29-10-2013 00:00:00` where I'm looking for this format: `29-10-10-29` without hour, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do you really want `29-10-10-29` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have some typos or misinformation in your post regarding the output you're getting and what you're desiring.

Based on what appears to be a misunderstanding of `moment`, however, I am pretty sure that what you want is:

```
value.game_date = '2013-10-27 03:39:35';

var formatted_game_date = moment(value.game_date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
// produces '27-10-2013'
```

`moment()` is a factory function which takes a date string and returns a `moment` instance. That `moment` instance then has various methods available, such as `format()` which takes a format string as the first param.

So your code is producing a `moment` instance representing current date/time (because you're not passing any params to `moment()`), then you ask `.format()` to return a string formatted using your date stamp as the formatter. Your date string doesn't have any of the things in it which `format` would parse and replace, so you just get back your date string.

The code I gave passes the date string to `moment` to produce the instance, then asks `.format()` for a formatted string using your desired format template.